# cordova-background-fetch will work when ios app is closed?

Tags: react-native, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have gone through documentation of the plugin . But I am still not sure whether the fetch event happens when app is killed/closed or only when it is in background . Some insight will be helpful

Comment: The documentation is pretty straightforward: "plugin which attempts to awaken an app in the background" If its killed or closed, no code can be executed.

Comment: yea thats what I thought . Again in few places they mentioned terminated case also. Strange